# SQL Query returning repeating information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having an issue where this query statement is giving me repeating GoalText in the results. Any ideas?

The complete query statement:

```
Select  g.GoalText, convert(nvarchar, g.GoalID) + '|' + convert(nvarchar, r.GoalReqID) as GoalID, GoalReqID
from Goal g inner join GoalRequirement r
on g.GoalID = r.GoalID 
where GoalReqID in
  (Select GoalReqID
  from GoalRequirement r inner join SurveyAnswer a
   on r.QuestionID = a.QuestionID and  ReqQuestionValue = SurveyAnswer 
   where a.CycleID = 93 and ReqBMILevel is null
  and ReqEnergyBalance is null and SurveyAnswer = 1 and r.QuestionID in
    (Select  QuestionID from Question where QuestionParent = 6000));
```

Results:

```
GoalText   GoalID  GoalReqID
Choose lasagna, ravioli, stuffed pasta 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  13|442  442
Choose macaroni and cheese 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  14|443  443
Choose meats in gravies- beef stew, chicken pot pie,… 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.   15|444  444
Choose spaghetti, meat sauce and/or meatballs, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  16|445  445
Choose tacos, burritos, enchiladas, nachos with meat and/or cheese 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  17|446  446
Choose biscuits and sausage gravy 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.   102|482 482
Choose pizza- all types and calzones 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    12|483  483
Choose hamburger/tuna/chicken noodle casseroles (includes “Helper”) 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week. 130|484 484
Choose lasagna, ravioli, stuffed pasta 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  13|485  485
Choose macaroni and cheese 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  14|486  486
Choose meats in gravies- beef stew, chicken pot pie,… 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.   15|487  487
Choose spaghetti- marinara sauce only, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  132|488 488
Choose spaghetti, meat sauce and/or meatballs, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  16|489  489
Choose tacos, burritos, enchiladas, nachos with meat and/or cheese 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  17|490  490
```

The individual queries that make up the query:

```
Select  g.GoalText, convert(nvarchar, g.GoalID) + '|' + convert(nvarchar, r.GoalReqID) as GoalID, GoalReqID
from Goal g inner join GoalRequirement r
on g.GoalID = r.GoalID
```

Results: There are 444 records in this query, but you should get the idea.

```
GoalText   GoalID  GoalReqID
Eat an additional 400-500 calories per day. 1|1 1
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|2 2
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|106   106
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|144   144
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|182   182
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|219   219
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|256   256
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|293   293
Choose fried potatoes, French fries, hash browns, potato salad 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.  2|330   330
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|331   331
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|294   294
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|257   257
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|220   220
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|183   183
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|145   145
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|107   107
Choose canned fruit, in heavy syrup, 1-3 times a week instead of 4 or more times a week.    3|3 3
Choose lower fat milk (nonfat, skim, 1%, 2%) instead of whole milk. 4|4 4
Choose lower fat milk (nonfat, skim, 1%, 2%) instead of whole milk. 4|108   108
Choose lower fat milk (nonfat, skim, 1%, 2%) instead of whole milk. 4|146   146
Choose lower fat milk (nonfat, skim, 1%, 2%) instead of whole milk. 4|184   184
Choose lower fat milk (nonfat, skim, 1%, 2%) instead of whole milk. 4|221   221
```

```
Select GoalReqID
  from GoalRequirement r inner join SurveyAnswer a
   on r.QuestionID = a.QuestionID and  ReqQuestionValue = SurveyAnswer 
   where a.CycleID = 93 and ReqBMILevel is null
  and ReqEnergyBalance is null and SurveyAnswer = 1
```

Results:

```
GoalReqID
478
479
480
481
482
440
441
483
484
485
442
443
486
487
444
488
489
445
```

```
Select  QuestionID from Question where QuestionParent = 6000
```

Results:

```
QuestionID
6000
6001
6002
6003
6004
6005
6006
6007
6008
6009
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're joining two tables together.  Obviously, records in the first table match more than one record from the 2nd table.  When that happens, the record from the first table is duplicated in the result set for every record in the 2nd table that it matches.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what's going on. Any suggestion for fixing my issue?

Comment: The simple answer is to just write your join so that the 1st table only matches one result in the 2nd. But to get that right, we need to better understand what criteria should define exactly which row that should be.

Answer (score 4):

Re-wrote your query so it's more readable, and turns subquerys (yuck) into JOINs:

```
SELECT g.goaltext
       g.goalid, 
       gr.goalreqid
  FROM GOAL g
  JOIN GOALREQUIREMENT gr ON gr.goalid = g.goalid AND gr.reqbmilevel IS NULL AND gr.reqenergybalance IS NULL
  JOIN JOIN SURVEYANSWER sa ON sa.questionid = gr.questionid AND sa.surveyanswer = gr.reqquestionvalue AND sa.surveyanswer = 1
  JOIN QUESTION q ON q.questionid = gr.questionid
 WHERE sa.cycleid = 93
```

It's the goalid and/or goalreqid column(s) that causing the rows to come out duplicated.  Because the goaltext column is associated to multiple goalid/etcs, you're never going to get single entries for goaltext while including goalids.

Answer (score 1):

When a row in the first table joins to more than one row in the 2nd table, you apparently only want it to show once in the query output.  In that case, WHICH row from the 2nd table do you want to show in this single output row??

- The row entered last?
- with biggest goalId?
- or whatever...

You need to answer this question before you can write a SQL query to do whatever your answer specifies..